# VBA Error 1004 When Calling A Module with an Argument

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

This is my first post so bear with me.

I get a run-time error 1004 when I try calling a module from my user form and passing on an argument. I'm sure the answer is pretty obvious but I'm new to passing on arguments.

From User Form when clicking submit button:

```
Sub SubmitButton_Click()

Dim addRowValue As Integer

addRowValue = LineBox.Value

MsgBox "Add " & addRowValue & " rows."
Call Sheet1.ResizeTable(addRowValue)

End Sub
```

From Sheet1:

```
Sub ResizeTable(addRowValue As Integer)

Dim rng As Range
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DATA_INPUT")

Set rng = Range("DATA_INPUT[#All]").Resize(tbl.Range.Rows.Count +  _
 addRowValue, tbl.Range.Columns.Count)

tbl.Resize rng

End Sub
```

`Call Sheet1.ResizeTable` works fine but when I add the argument is when I get the error. Also, the module `ResizeTable()` works fine when I change the variable `addRowValue` to a set number and run it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are assigning a string to variable of type integer.

Change

```
addRowValue = LineBox.Value
```

To

```
addRowValue = CInt(LineBox.Value)
```

EDIT: You might also want to ensure the user enters a numeric value so have something like:

```
If IsNumeric(LineBox.Value) Then
    addRowValue = CInt(LineBox.Value)
Else
    MsgBox "Please enter numeric value", vbCritical
    LineBox.Value = ""
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I made the change but I'm still getting the same error. Any other suggestions? It's an application defined or object defined error, if that helps.

Comment: At `Call Sheet1.ResizeTable(addRowValue)`, I can add the code for the text box aswell if that will help.

Comment: That is what I thought. Is Sheet1 the name of the tab, or is it the name of  of the object?

Comment: The object (maybe?) the tab name is "DATA_INPUT".

Comment: Any chance you post a link with the actual workbook. I will take a look. This is the most efficient way

Comment: Well I feel dumb... It turns out my code was fine, the error was because the sheet was protected. Thanks for your time and all the help!